# Scraping Network tab of a Webpage using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im currently using bs4 and requests to scrape Discords webpage, but i dont know how or if it is possible to use these to grab the information from the network tab in the Inspect menu [Like in this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWL5Z.png)

currently i only have this code in place for grabbing the HTML info but i know its probably not enough

```
URL = "https://discord.com/channels/@me"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

print(soup)
```

ATM i am only getting the Webpage HTML code and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

No.  The network tab is a feature of the browser, not the webpage.

You might be able to do this with some other tool that loads the webpage in a browser, but that's not how BS works.